# Full path with double backslash (C#)

Tags: c#, filepath

Is it possible to get a full path with double backslash by using `Path.GetFullPath`? Something like this:

```
C:\\Users\\Mammamia\\Videos\\Documents\\CFD\\geo_msh\\cubeOp.txt
```

instead of this:

```
C:\Users\Mammamia\Videos\Documents\CFD\geo_msh\cubeOp.txt
```

Or is there any other method?

Comment: Maybe `string.Replace` with `@"\"` to `@"\\"`?

Comment: Why do you need it like this? You can replace single \ with double \\ easily anyway.

Comment: @Aamir: Because, later this file will be used by C++.

Comment: Also, MSBuild needs the double slashes to handle paths with spaces in them properly. I realize this question was asked 3 years ago, but I was looking to see if there was an alternative to doing the string replace and came across it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
Path.GetFullPath(path).Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

Comment: Depending on his requirements this could lead to unexpected results if `Path.GetFullPath` returns an UNC path like `@"\\myserver\myshare\some\file.txt"`.

Comment: I agree @Uwe - not sure why you'd want to do that, but hey - it's an answer! :)

Comment: this is result : D:\\\\Programing\\\\DMS\\\\FileTable.Api\\\...

Answer (score 3):

`C:\\Users\\Mammamia\\Videos\\Documents\\CFD\\geo_msh\\cubeOp.txt` is not a valid path, so I'm not sure why you'd want it, but:

```
Path.GetFullPath(yourPath).Replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Comment: string.Replace takes char too as parameters. `.Replace('\', '\\')` should be enough.

Comment: @nawfal '\\' is not a char.

Comment: @BurakKarakuş you're right. I had no idea what I was thinking when I made that comment...

Comment: Two slashes is valid.

Comment: @DanGifford Yes, but it's not a valid path. With the slashes escaped the path would look lie `C:\\\\Users\\\\Mammamia\\\\Videos\\\\Documents\\\\CFD\\\\geo_msh\\\\cubeOp.txt`

Comment: @Rick.Okelly - Two slashes is valid without the @ literal symbol.  That is what I meant.  Four slashes presents quite a mess.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this:

```
Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\\Users\\Mammamia\\Videos\\Documents\\CFD\\geo_msh\\cubeOp.txt")
```

But i'm not sure why, you want to escape the \ ?

If yes, you can do just this :

```
 Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Mammamia\Videos\Documents\CFD\geo_msh\cubeOp.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing a String.replace().  I recently had to do this in a project for myself.  So if you do something similar to:

```
String input = Path.GetFullPath(x);
input = input.Replace("\\","\\\\");
```

I am fairly confident that is what you need :)

Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

just apply an @ sign before the string:

String k = @"C:\temp\myfile.txt";

Comment: This does not answer the original question.