# Transform String Folder Path

Tags: c#, string, dotnetzip

I'm doing a C# project for school.

I need to extract a `.zip` file but i have a problem.

I get the path where the file that is going to be extract is with `FolderBrowserDialog` and everything is ok, but the `FolderBrowserDialog` gives me something like `"C:\Users\Zé Eduardo\Music"` , but i need something like this `"C:\\Users\\Zé Eduardo\\Music"`.

How can i transform `"\"` to `"\\"`?

Comment: I may have missed something, but I don't see any difference between what you get and what you want to get...

Comment: @Bartdude I've editing the question, the double slash was being escaped

Comment: Why do you need to double the `\\`? It is not generally needed.

Comment: Oh ok; If you mean you have double slash in the debugger, that's normal : try displaying the value and you'll see there's no double slash in it...

Comment: can you show the code where you call `FolderBrowserDialog`, I suspect you don't actually have a problem, its just the way you inspect the path string.

Comment: The program that i am using to unzip the .zip file don´t accept the path "C:\Users\Zé Eduardo\Music" and only works with "C:\\Users\\Zé Eduardo\\Music". I am using dotnetzip 1.9

Comment: Have you tried `path.Replace(@"\",@"\\")`

Comment: I search a lot , i can´t find the problem :O

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294133/full-path-with-double-slash-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, this is the answer to your question but you are probably asking the wrong question,

```
var transformedString = badString.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

---

The `@` in the literal means, this is a verbatim string so normal escaping rules don't apply. Effectively, you don't need to escape the escape character.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , problem solved , the unzip reference only works with "\\" . Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Something simple would be to use string replace:

```
String original = @"c:\some\path";
String @fixed = original.Replace("\\", "\\\\"); //Note the double escaping!

//fixed contains "c:\\some\\path"
```

Comment: erm, isn't `fixed` a keyword??????

Comment: Thanks a lot , I don´t know why but the program just extract my .zip file with "\\" . Your answer is right , thanks a lot for the help :)