# Directory.Exists checking against path with multiiple slashes

Tags: c#

The legit path is: `@"S:\Personal Folders\UserA\test`

Why does the `Directory.Exists` return True on below path?

`@"S:\Personal Folders\UserA\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\test`

Or even more slashes.

PS:I tested with `File.Move`, it was not recognizing that as a valid path.

Comment: The bigger question: why use Directory.Exists() at all? In most cases it's MUCH slower (adds an extra file system lookup from disk), and doesn't save you from still needing an exception handler.

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294133/full-path-with-double-backslash-c

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Much slower than what? Sorry but I feel like I'm missing a piece of context from your comment.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Slower than just using the untested path and letting the exception happen. As slow as exceptions are, file system access is WAY worse.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Really?  So it's faster to do a file operation and have it possibly fail and throw than to wrap the operation in an if/exists.  Hmmm... Who knew?  I guess since the if/exists gets called on both the success and failure situations, where the exception only occurs on failure, skipping the test optimizes the success path.

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, it's better for success. For the failure path, remember there are two failure modes to think about when using `Exists()`: one where you fail because your test returned "false" (costs one disk access) and one where you fail for a reason reason `.Exists()` couldn't handle (costs the disk access _and_ the exception). There are several reasons this can happen (permissions, network or fs lock, file system redirector, volatile file system, etc). You still need the exception handler; `Exists()` doesn't save writing that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path with slashes still satisfied Absolute Path standards.

According to [the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks),

> The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information.

**Edit: [Reference for Path Normalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats?view=netframework-4.7.2#path-normalization)**

> Almost all paths passed to Windows APIs are normalized. During
>   normalization, Windows performs the following steps:
>
> - Identifies the path.
> - Applies the current directory to partially qualified (relative) paths.
> - Canonicalizes component and directory separators.
> - Evaluates relative directory components (. for the current directory and .. for the parent directory).
> - Trims certain characters.
>
> This normalization happens implicitly, but you can do it explicitly by
>   calling the Path.GetFullPath method, which wraps a call to the
>   GetFullPathName() function. You can also call the Windows
>   GetFullPathName() function directly using P/Invoke.

**Edit**

Not Every function normalizes paths by default.

`File.Move` by myself gives error for this path.

on the other hand,

```
var parsedPath = Path.GetFullPath("S:\\Personal Folders\\UserA\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\test");
File.Move(parsedPath, ...);
```

does not.

Comment: Thank you, but why I test with `File.Move`, it seems that path cannot be recognized as a valid directory?

Comment: check my edit please

Comment: Odd, according to the File.Move source it should be doing the GetFullPath internally.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,9635b474663856ac

Comment: @LONG which framework and version are you using?